# How to calculate the required pipe diameter to achieve a certain mass flow rate at a certain pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

Assume incompressible fluid with known density. Any gravity effect can be ignored.

I need to have a certain mass flow rate through a pipe. The pressure of the fluid arriving at the pipe is known (fluid is fed at a constant, regulated pressure). I want to calculate the diameter required to achieve the said mass flow rate.

If the calculation is not possible with the given variables, what more do I need to know?

Comment: Darcy Weisbach formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation

Comment: Start by calculating the pipe size that will give you a velocity of 5 ft/sec.  Then choose the next larger standard pipe size.  Note that any flow control valves in the system (which should be required) will tend to correct for the roughness of this method.